# Cypher queries: misuse of the with clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am now starting approaching Cypher and I have probably a trivial question; so i provide an example query to make you understand what i mean:

```
match (p1:Person)-[:works_on]->(project1:Project), (p2:Person)-[:works_on]->(project2:Project), (p1)-[:interested_in]->(interest:Skill)<-[:interested_in]-(p2)
where id(p1)>id(p2) 
with p1,p2, interest, count(interest) as conto
return p1.name, p2.name, count(interest) ,conto,  collect(interest.name) as interessi
```

results:

```
╒════════╤═════════╤═══════════════╤═════╤══════════════════════════╕
│p1.name │p2.name  │count(interest)│conto│interessi                 │
╞════════╪═════════╪═══════════════╪═════╪══════════════════════════╡
│"Sarah" │"Charlie"│1              │2    │["DBMS"]                │
├────────┼─────────┼───────────────┼─────┼──────────────────────────┤
│"Sarah" │"Ben"    │2              │2    │["DBMS", "TRAVEL"]        │
├────────┼─────────┼───────────────┼─────┼──────────────────────────┤
│"Ben"   │"Charlie"│1              │1    │["DBMS"]                │
├────────┼─────────┼───────────────┼─────┼──────────────────────────┤
│"Arnold"│"Sarah"  │3              │2    │["TRAVEL", "JAVA", "DBMS"]│
├────────┼─────────┼───────────────┼─────┼──────────────────────────┤
│"Arnold"│"Ben"    │2              │1    │["TRAVEL", "DBMS"]        │
├────────┼─────────┼───────────────┼─────┼──────────────────────────┤
│"Arnold"│"Charlie"│1              │1    │["DBMSs"]                │
```

The thing I'd like to understand is why the 2 columns `count(interest)` and `conto` differ. Why? what is the latter actually counting?

Answer (score 1):

In a `WITH` or `RETURN` clause, an [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/) (like [COLLECT](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect)) aggregates over the [grouping keys](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#grouping-keys) (i.e., non-aggregating expressions) in the same clause.

Therefore:

1. In `WITH p1, p2, interest, COUNT(interest) AS conto`:

   - `conto` is the number of `interest` nodes associated with each unique set of `p1`, `p2`, and `interest` values.
2. In `RETURN p1.name, p2.name, COUNT(interest), conto, COLLECT(interest.name) AS interessi`:

   - `COUNT(interest)` is the number of `interest` nodes associated with each unique set of `p1.name`, `p2.name`, and `conto` values.
   - `interessi` is a collection of `interest.name` values associated with each unique set of `p1.name`, `p2.name`, and `conto` values.

In summary, since #1 and #2 have different grouping keys, the `COUNT(interest`) values are different as well.